# Derive a table from two others in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two view.

view Coconut. This I got this from a table which shows the complete amount spent by a person on buying coconuts.

```
+---------+---------+
| RollNo  | Coconut |
+---------+---------+
| 341401  |    NULL |
| 341402  |    NULL |
| 341403  |    NULL |
| 341405  |      30 |
| 341406  |    NULL |
| 341407  |    NULL |
| 341408  |      30 |
| 341409  |    NULL |
---------------------
```

view coconut2. This one I got from same table but with a constraint on date.

```
+---------+----------+
| RollNo  | Coconut  |
+---------+----------+
| 341405  |       20 |
| 341408  |       15 |
+---------+----------+
```

Now I want the final output be like

```
+---------+---------+
| RollNo  | Amount  |
+---------+---------+
| 341401  |    NULL |
| 341402  |    NULL |
| 341403  |    NULL |
| 341405  |      20 |
| 341406  |    NULL |
| 341407  |    NULL |
| 341408  |      15 |
| 341409  |    NULL |
---------------------
```

Which means I want all roll numbers to be shown. Amount of Whatever roll number is not present in the second view should be seen as null in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried FULL OUTER JOIN?

```
SELECT * FROM coconut v1 FULL JOIN coconut2 v2 ON v1.RollNo = v2.RollNo
```

Ideally you should be naming column Coconut2 as Coconut!

Answer (score 0):

After trying for some time I got this answer.

```
select c.RollNo,c2.coconut from coconut c left join coconut2 c2 on c.ROllNo=c2.RollNo;
```